# execute batch file remotely java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I want to execute a bat file located remotely on server 
`\\testserver\someFolderName\test.bat`.
I am using process builder and wanted to chande the directory with
`procbuilder.directory(....),`
but could not succeed.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In the past I've done it quick and dirty with [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

Just start that from your program as its own process with the required arguments to gain access to the batch on the remote computer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do UNC paths for the ProcessBuilder, but it doesn't really matter in any case.

To run a .bat file, you need to run a windows command shell and have that execute the .bat file, and the command shell doesn't support UNC paths... The way around it is to run your command like this:

```
cmd.exe /C "pushd \\testserver\someFolderName && test.bat && popd"
```

Essentially, you're telling the cmd prompt to mount your remote folder as a temporary drive (pushd \testserver\someFolderName), run test.bat and then unmount the temporary drive (popd).

Comment: is code like this:
String[] command = { "CMD", "/C", "pushd \\\\testserver\\someFolderName && test.bat && popd" };
  ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);

Comment: String[] command = { "cmd.exe", "/C", "pushd \\\\testserver\\someFolderName && test.bat && popd" };
  
  ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
I tried this but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Your question was unclear (To me at any rate). I thought you wanted to run the remotely located .bat file locally. Andrew's answer would be more relevant then.

Answer (score 1):

This is working code that we are using currently:

```
try {            
   ProcessBuilder launcher = new ProcessBuilder();
   Map<String, String> environment = launcher.environment();
   launcher.redirectErrorStream(true);
   launcher.directory(new File("\\\\<your remote computer name>\\TIERS\\DEV1\\RP\\VISUAL_BASIC\\"));

   environment.put("name", "var");
   launcher.command("your.exe");
   Process p = launcher.start(); // And launch a new process

} catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The system cannot find the file specified is my result.
Executing with the same path and executable name in explorer does work, so the path and executable name are correct.

Answer (score 1):

it also works in java as below:

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C pushd \\yourserver\yourfolderpath && yourexecutable.bat && popd");
```

Comment: This worked for me through Java. But I had to escape the url.- \\\\yourserver\\yourfolderpath. Thanks!