# Need help on executing a batch file located remotely

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a batch file located on a remote computer and i want to execute this file.
I have to execute it using java so i have 2 options

1. call the remote file directly from java program OR
2. create a batch file locally to call the remote batch file and then invoke the local batch file.

Can anyone please help me achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [execute batch file remotely java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621231/execute-batch-file-remotely-java). However, the post is a few years old, so might not apply anymore. But if I do a Google search for "java run batch file remote server" I get a bunch of responses

Comment: What does this have to do with powershell?

Comment: i thought power shell might have some option in copy command to get this  done directly. removed powershell tag now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a batch file that would execute the remote batch file.
This can be achieved rather easily using [Psexec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) found in [Sysinternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx)

Sample Execution:

```
Psexec.exe \\RemoteMachineName -u Username -p Password C:\PathToBatch\Batch.bat
```